# Get UIFontWeight of UIFont by fontName

Tags: ios, swift

I try to display all ios system fonts and their UIFontWeights.
If I know a name UIFont I can get UIFontWeight of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for listing all fonts inside your app, including system fonts and all weights.

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames {
    print("\(family)")
    for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
        print("== \(names)")
    }
}
```